# How can I revert a branch after resetting it hard to a previous commit of another branch?

Tags: git

I was working on my branch (branch1) and realized I didn't like my last push. So I reverted it to the previous commit using the command `git reset --hard <commit_number>` and `git push --force`. But by accident, I ran these commands in another branch (branch2). I hadn't realized that I wasn't on branch1. So, branch2 was completely overwritten by my commit that was intended for branch1. Luckily, I have the commit_number of the last commit of branch2, and now need to update branch2 to go back to that commit. I tried running the command `git reset --hard <branch2_commit_number>` and `git push --force`, but I get this error in the console:

```
fatal: branch2 cannot be resolved to branch
user:~projectDirectory$ fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly                                             

remote:                                                                                                                                                
remote: ========================================================================                                                                       
remote:                                                                                                                                                
remote: ERROR: user canceled the push                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
remote:                                                                                                                                                
remote: ========================================================================                                                                       
remote:
```

Is there anyway to revert branch2 to the previous commit even though the head for branch2 now points to a commit that was intended for branch1? Is this a permissions thing or am I missing a command?

Comment: Can you run `git branch -a` and let us know what you see there for `branch1` and `branch2`?

Comment: `git branch -f branch2 $commit_which_you_noted_down` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can force/recreate branch2 using [git switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git switch -C branch2 <yourOldCommit>
git push --force -u origin branch2
```